# Create unique and fix id for particular schema key

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How can I match and create unique and fix id for particular schema key value.

I have following schema :

```
var adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company  name can't be empty."
                },  
    companyID:  {
                type: String, 
                default: function(){ 
                    return Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000); 
                    } 
                }
});
```

I can generate random 4 digit `companyID`. Now I need to create `companyID` based on `companyName`. If `companyName` string value entered is same as before then same `companyID` must be generated.

Any suggestion to achieve this ?

Comment: you need a hash function that outputs the same string with same input, something like md5.

Comment: @DakshMiglani I guess I am doing something wrong. I have added this `var reqq  = crypto.createHash('md5').update(companyName).digest("hex");
console.log(reqq);` . How can I update a schema here ?

Comment: use the md5 module, `npm install md5 --save`. then you can run it like: `md5(string)`

Comment: @DakshMiglani I can generate the md5 key but how will I convert it to only 4 digit number ?

Comment: well you can slice the string, but that won't be a good idea because collisions can happen more easily.

Comment: @DakshMiglani exactly. Can I pass the string to math function ? Any idea ?